# Is there some security advantage to using pgcrypto instead of partition-level encryption?

Tags: postgresql, encryption

The document here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/encryption-options.html describes several approaches to encrypting data when using postgresql.

I would like to know if there's any security advantage to encrypting specific columns using pgcrypto instead of simply encrypting the entire partition on which the database resides. It seems to me that pgcrypto is cumbersome to use(instead of just using SQL queries without having to worry about things being encrypted) so there should be a reason for its existence. Is it simply that people may not have the ability to manage the database server(shared hosts/etc...) so they would have to make-do with pgcrypto, or is there a security reason?

In my particular case, the application code and the database are on the same host, so compromising the server itself while it is live would result in the data being leaked either way(one could look for the encryption key in the code in one case, or simply retrieve the data from the mounted volume in the other).

Edit: I forgot to mention, also in this particular case, the data is used by the server not the client, ie, the client can't provide the key at run-time it would have to be on the server in the application code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You can give the DBA SQL level access without compromising data.
- You can have separate encryption keys for different data
- Your backups (dumps) are encrypted
- <strike>If the client provides the encryption keys, The server does not have to be trusted</strike>
- If You separate the app server from the DB server, the encryption keys can be on the app server only.
- You can encrypt only a part of the data.
- Last but not the least: There is more to pgcrypto than symmetric single-key encryption, like asymmetric encryption, cryptographic hashing, cryto-safe PRNG, password-hashing.

Comment: _"If the client provides the encryption keys, The server does not have to be trusted"_ is not exactly correct, given that when using pgcrypto the key is SENT to the DB server and therefore, within reach of compromise in case the DB server (but not the app server) have been compromised.

As the page he linked states: _"The decrypted data and the decryption key are present on the server...This presents a brief moment where the **data and keys can be intercepted by someone with complete access to the database server**, such as the system administrator."_